# Shapley Value Calculation

Tags: game-theory

I have a problem using Shapley value. I have a 3-person game. Related to the Shapley value definition, all coalitions are possible (2^3 = 8 coalitions). But my game is in the real world and 2 of my players cannot cooperate and make a coalition.
For example let N={A,B,C}
My feasible coalitions (except null) are: {A},{B},{C},{AB,C},{A,BC} and {ABC}.
I'm wondering if someone could help me how should I calculate the Shapley value for above set of coalitions.
Regards

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please see [this tutorial and reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) on how to typeset math on this site.